# How to loop in a function, and keep taking inputs in python

Tags: python, function, while-loop

So I was making a simple rock paper scissors game, and I wanted to put it as a function. I also wanted it to loop 10 times before deciding if the user won or lost. But the code just doesn't work and keeps giving random errors.

```
#code for rock paper scissors
import random 

l = ["rock","paper","scissors"]

def rps():
    q = 0
    wincount = 0
    while q < 10:
        w = random.choice(l)
        x = input("Choose rock paper or scissors all lowercase: ") 
        if w == "rock":
            if x == "rock":
                print("It's a draw")
            if x == "paper":
                print("You lost :(")
            if x == "scissors":
                print("You win!")
                wincount += 1
        elif w == "paper":
            if x == "rock":
                print("You lost :(")
            if x == "paper":
                print("It's a draw")
            if x == "scissors":
                print("You win!") 
                wincount += 1
        elif w == "scissors":
            if x == "rock":
                print("You win!")
                wincount += 1
            if x == "paper":
                print("You lost :(")
            if x == "scissors":
                print("It's a draw")
        q += 1
    if wincount >= 5:
        print("You won the game!")
```

The error is

````
PS D:\project percy> & C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe "d:/project percy/cogs/asiufysduifhi.py"
PS D:\project percy> rps()
At line:1 char:5
+ rps()
+     ~
An expression was expected after '('.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordE  
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedExpression```
````

Comment: What IDE are you using, this doesn't look like a standard Python error message.

Comment: you're trying to run python code directly in the terminal, that second line should be within the code or the first file imported to a python shell

Answer (score 1):

The error seems not because of python. It should be because of Powershell.

PowerShell needs the ampersand to interpret the string as a filename.

As you are already using ampersand so not sure but try to run your command within proper quotes.

Like

```
& "C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe" "d:/project percy/cogs/asiufysduifhi.py"
```

Or if above wont works then give a try to this:

```
& "C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe" d:/project percy/cogs/asiufysduifhi.py
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said already, he error does not come from python but rather from powershell. I don't have windows to test but I think the problem is that you are trying to call `rps()` which is a python function, from the powershell prompt:

```
PS D:\project percy> & C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe "d:/project percy/cogs/asiufysduifhi.py"
```

Call your python file that defines the function BUT NEVER CALLS IT

```
PS D:\project percy> rps()
```

Try to execute a powershell command named rps, which might exist but should be called differently.

#### Proposed solution

Try to add `rps()` at the end of your python file:

```
def rps():
    .....
    if wincount >= 5:
        print("You won the game!")

rps()
```

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is you forgot to pass the list to the function as well as calling the function.

**try this:**

```
# code for rock paper scissors
import random

l = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]


def rps(l):
    q = 1
    wincount = 0
    while q < 11:
        w = random.choice(l)
        print()
        print(q, "time")
        x = input(f" Choose rock paper or scissors all lowercase: ")
        if w == "rock":
            if x == "rock":
                print("It's a draw")
            if x == "paper":
                print("You lost :")
            if x == "scissors":
                print("You win!")
                wincount += 1
        elif w == "paper":
            if x == "rock":
                print("You lost :")
            if x == "paper":
                print("It's a draw")
            if x == "scissors":
                print("You win!")
                wincount += 1
        elif w == "scissors":
            if x == "rock":
                print("You win!")
                wincount += 1
            if x == "paper":
                print("You lost :")
            if x == "scissors":
                print("It's a draw")
        q += 1
    if wincount >= 5:
        print("You won the game!")

calling = rps(l)
```